# PHP-CGI Crash on IIS

Tags: php, iis

I am running around 50 sugar CRM running sites on the following setup -

- IIS 7.5
- MS-SQL 2008 (Seperate Server)
- PHP 5.3.26

On average 5 out of 50 of the applications crash a day, and I have to restart the application pool to bring the site back up. I have asked end users what they were doing before the crash in an attempt to replicate this in a test environment. However I cannot seem to do it. I can only assume that I cannot do this in my test environment as it's under a lot less load.

I am pushing our development team to upgrade to the latest version of PHP for security and performance reasons, however my plea is falling on deaf ears.

Here is the error that I'm getting. Any advice at all will be appreciated.

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 5.3.26.0, time stamp: 0x51af72a9
Faulting module name: kernel32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18409, time stamp: 0x53159a85
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00011359
Faulting process id: 0x1aac
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfa72d28b47c94
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
Report Id: 8d025994-132e-11e4-b2f1-005056b32471
```

Comment: What (additional) PHP modules do you have installed, Ioncube Loader or Wincache perhaps?

Comment: Wincache is definitely enabled. Version 1.1.0630.0,

Comment: Ioncube is not enabled? Can you run PHP from the command line without problems? E.g.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe -c C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.wincache.ini -v`  will print out the version number (in my scenario, I have a different php.ini and IIS FastCgi handler for WinCache), or does this crash too?

Comment: ioncube isnt enabled. I don't have a php.wincache.ini file in that directory. I'm going to try and update winache to version 1.3.4

Comment: Well I said I have a php.wincache.ini file, because I created it. It might be you have WinCache enabled in the default php.ini file, then just use file that instead of php.wincache.ini :)

Comment: so I upgraded to 1.3.4, I had one application crash today. This time the error message said Faulting module path: E:\PHP\ext\php_wincache.dll

Comment: If I run E:\PHP\php-cgi.exe -c E:\PHP\php.wincache.ini -v I get PHP 5.3.26 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jun  5 2013 19:16:28)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

Comment: I realize this is an old thread, but am experiencing similar problems with WinCache. Any luck figuring this out? Also, where are you seeing these errors? PHP logs?

Comment: I never found a solution unfortunately. The errors can be seen in the Windows Event log. We decided to build a LAMP stack and migrate sites on to there.